# How can I add d3 zoom and pan to a Power BI visual?

Tags: d3.js, typescript, svg, powerbi

I've got a Power BI scatterchart visual that I want to add d3 zoom and pan to. I've seen all kinds of simple examples for using d3 to add zoom and pan, but none of them are specific to Power BI. They all appear to be html examples and I'm having trouble translating them into my Power BI typescript visual. I'm not sure what parts of the examples should go where. For example, what 
(if anything) should go in the constructor area versus the update area of the code.

My constructor has:

```
        constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
        this.host = options.host;
        this.selectionManager = options.host.createSelectionManager();
        this.tooltipServiceWrapper = createTooltipServiceWrapper(this.host.tooltipService, options.element);

        let svg = this.svg = d3.select(options.element)
            .append('svg')
            .classed('scatterChart', true);

        this.plotContainer = svg.append('g')
            .classed('plotContainer', true);

        this.xAxis = svg.append('g')
            .classed('xAxis', true);

        this.yAxis = svg.append('g')
            .classed('yAxis', true);
    }
```

I was thinking I'd need to tie the zoom to either `this.svg` or `this.plotContainer`. But, assuming I would, should I do that in the constructor or later in the code...in the update area? I've mostly attempted it in the update area because I figure zoom would be triggered by an active event and that is where such things are usually addressed.

When I have tried to lay in the various examples, with all the parts where I *think* they should be, the compiler always chokes on the function:

```
function zoomed() {
     this.plotContainer.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

It doesn't like `d3.event.translate` or `d3.event.scale`.

I'm really quite lost and could definitely use your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here are the parts of what worked for me:

I added this at the start of the visual's class...after the part that says "export class [VISUAL'S NAME (e.g., scatterChart)] implements IVisual {":

```
        private container: d3.Selection<SVGElement>;
```

I added this in the 'constructor' as a wrapper:

```
        this.container = svg.append("g");
```

The rest of this, I put in 'update'.

This, I believe, is referred to as a 'listener':

```
        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, 10])
            .on("zoom", this.zoomed.bind(this));
```

Here's the call to zoom.

```
        this.svg.call(zoom);
```

And this is the 'zoomed' function, which does the zoom and pan:

```
    private zoomed() {
        this.container.attr("transform", "translate(" + ((<any>d3.event).translate) + ")scale(" + ((<any>d3.event).scale) + ")");}
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this as well. In the end, my solution was upgrading my custom visual to D3 version 7 with latest TypeScript bindings.

Described at https://nonodename.com/post/pbid3zoom/